# Is it possible to write extension methods for Console?

Tags: c#, console, extension-methods

While looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655318/how-to-set-default-input-value-in-net-console-app) and it's answers I thought that it would be a good idea to write an extension method for `System.Console` that contained the desired functionality.

However, when I tried it, I got this compiler error

> System.Console': static types cannot
>   be used as parameters

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class ConsoleExtensions
    {
        [Extension]
        public static string TestMethod(this Console console, string testValue)
        {
            return testValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Is there another way of creating extension methods for static types? Or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No it's not possible unfortunately. See [Static extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods)

A few people have suggested it:
http://madprops.org/blog/static-extension-methods/

...but it was never done in .NET 4. Apparently extension properties got someway to making it but was then abandoned.

https://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties.aspx

Answer (score 34):

It's not possible, as mentioned in Matt's answer.

As a workaround you could create a static class that will wrap Console adding desired functionality.

```
public static class ConsoleEx
{
    public static void WriteLineRed(String message)
    {
        var oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
    }
}
```

It's not ideal, as you have to add that little "Ex", but flows with code decently well, if that's any (ehm) consolation:

```
ConsoleEx.WriteLineRed("[ERROR]")
```