# Console.ReadLine("Default Text Editable Text On Line")

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

Is there way of achieving this? I want to pass some text and have it appear on the input line -- instead of "**Enter your Name:<cursor>**", I want "**Enter your Name:Default Editable Text<cursor>**"

Comment: This may be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1655318/1108263

Comment: I think it's moreso a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565415/edit-text-in-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: This question hasn't solution.... :(

Answer (score 17):

Ok, found it. Sorry.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Your editable text:");
    SendKeys.SendWait("hello"); //hello text will be editable :)
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This will have interesting side-effects when your console window doesn't have the focus.

Comment: Yes, but I am only doing this immediately following dos line instigation of my program. The program (right now at least) is interactive from the command line and retains session info between calls. Eventually it will not bounce back into dos.

Comment: Can't find `SendKeys`.

Comment: SendKeys is not contains in Console

Comment: @nim using System.Windows.Forms; and it should work.

Comment: In my case, simply adding a `using` to the class didn't work; received [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639468/c-forms-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-windows/6639482). You may need to add a reference by right-clicking on **References** in Solution Explorer, clicking **Add Reference...**, and checking **System.Windows.Forms** under **Assemblies > Framework**.

Answer (score 3):

Assign the default value to your string and replace it only if the user has entered something.

```
Dim name, s As String

name = "John"
Console.Write($"Enter your Name (hit <Enter> for ""{name}""): ")
s = Console.ReadLine()
If Trim(s) <> "" Then
    name = s
End If
Console.WriteLine("Result = {0}", name)
Console.ReadKey()
```